# How to align background-image?

Tags: html, css

i would like to align orange basket, to the right, cca 5px from the text, and it should change according to lenght of the text. Thanks for your advices. I am novice.

Page: http://attractivebohemianglass.com/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sry, it is approximately

Comment: Your cart image is a background on the container. You won't be able to easily position it with respect to text unless its on an inner element.

Comment: How many of those "unvisible" spans might be showing at one time?

Comment: maximum of unvisible spans: 2

Comment: Here's how I'd set up this sort of thing. Without specifics in your question (a simplified case), I can't give a proper answer. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/cvfkvm0L

Answer (score 0):

You should set to your `<a>` tag this:

```
a #ikonka {
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px; 
}
```

Comment: This is extremely fragile as it only works in this one specific scenario. If anything about the contents of `#ikonka` changes (and OP said it will), it breaks.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt change according to text.

Comment: This just fixes the problem that the cart is near (empty), but if you want that it also according to text than you should define for your cart and your text in a seperate `<div>`. @isherwood make a great example just look in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ClassName{
    background-image:(ImagePath);
    background-position -5px 0px;
}
```